# Combine all txt files in an S3 bucket into 1 large file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Problem:** I am trying to combine large amounts of small-sized text files into 1 large-sized file in S3 bucket. Using python:

The code I tested to try this locally is below. It works perfectly. (obtained from another post):

```
with open(outfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
    for filename in glob.glob('UBXEvents*'):
        if filename == outfilename: # don't want to copy the output into the output
            continue
        with open(filename, 'rb') as readfile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(readfile, outfile)
```

Now, since my files are located in an S3 bucket, I have trouble referencing the S3 bucket. I wanted to run this code for all files (using wild card *) in an S3 but I am having a hard time connecting the two.

Below is the s3 object I created:

```
object = client.get_object(
    Bucket= 'my_bucket_name',
    Key='bucket_path/prefix_of_file_name*'
    )
```

**Question:** How would I reference the S3 bucket/path in my combining code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Obtaining a list of files**

You can obtain a list of files in the bucket like this:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket', Prefix = 'folder1/')

for object in response['Contents']:
    # Do stuff here
    print(object['Key'])
```

**Reading & Writing to Amazon S3**

Normally, you would need to **download** each file from Amazon S3 to the local disk (using `download_file()` and then read the contents). However, you might instead want to use [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/), which is a library that allows files to be opened on S3 using similar syntax to the normal Python `open()` command.

Here's a program that uses `smart-open` to read files from S3 and combine them into an output file in S3:

```py
import boto3
from smart_open import open

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
PREFIX = 'folder1/' # Optional

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# Open output file with smart-open
with open(f's3://{BUCKET}/out.txt', 'w') as out_file:

    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=BUCKET, Prefix = PREFIX)

    for object in response['Contents']:
        print(f"Copying {object['Key']}")

        # Open input file with smart-open
        with open(f"s3://{BUCKET}/{object['Key']}", 'r') as in_file:
            
            # Read content from input file
            for line in in_file:
                    
                    # Write content to output file
                    out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes sense. I tried running this code and it seemed to work for a bit (files being opened etc.) and then it showed an error. Below is the actual error. I am guessing there is some content in some of the files that it can't open..?  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 931: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by adding 'encoding="utf8"' within the open function.